# How to convert a String variable to a Raster datatype using Calculate Value

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing, arcgis-flex-api

I have a GP service I would like to consume in a Flex application, but one of the input data types can be a raster. ArcGIS Server does not support a raster data type as an input parameter, but according to their documentation here - [Input and Output Data Types](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Input_and_output_data_types/002v00000004000000/) - you can create a variable in your model/script of type String and convert that into the data type your model requires. In their example they use an Areal Unit, but I need to convert to a raster dataset/raster layer. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the [docs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Input_and_output_data_types/002v00000004000000/) correctly, isn't it just a matter of selecting "Raster Dataset" from the Data type dropdown and feeding in your string value as the Expression, and that will convert it from string to raster?

[image]

Comment: I've tried that, but I have run into two issues: 1) The String representation of a raster dataset is the catalogPath. When I use that as the value for the string I get a syntax error. 2) I have no idea what to do with the output, it just says "1" and cannot be changed